# how to change default db from sqlite to postgresql/mysql in jupyter notebook

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, database-locking

I can see there are some config options in [jupyter_notebook_config.py](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) related to default database which is sqlite

```
## The sqlite file in which to store notebook signatures. By default, this will
#  be in your Jupyter data directory. You can set it to ':memory:' to disable
#  sqlite writing to the filesystem.
#c.NotebookNotary.db_file = ''


## A callable returning the storage backend for notebook signatures. The default
#  uses an SQLite database.
#c.NotebookNotary.store_factory = traitlets.Undefined
```

Now I want to change this default db to some relational db like postgresql/mysql as we are frequently getting [database locked error](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/issues/52). currently this platform is used by multiple users for python practice. we spawn separate notebook for each user.

How can we specify the mysql/postgresql database in the configuration of jupyter notebook.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: My requirements may be different from you but I have solved this problem by installing `pip install psycopg2-binary`.